# Build-in Excel function not working in VBA code - What is my mistake?

Tags: excel, vba, function

I am trying to sum up all values of a predefined range of cells. However, that range has been defined by rows only (e.g. searchRngQue = Rows 5 to 10). I now tried the following to extract the row numbers from the range and add the relevant Column to define the exact cells from which the sum should be calculated.
However the code gives me the Run-time Error 1004: "Application-defined or object-defined error"

Another problem seems to be that the .End(xlUp/xlDown) methods are not returning the first/last row of the range. What should I use instead?
Can anyone show me what I am missing?! Thanks a lot in advance!

```
sumQue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range(.Cells(searchRngQue.End(xlUp).Row, 8) & ":" & .Cells(searchRngQue.End(xlDown).Row, 8)))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You meant to do this:

```
sumQue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range(.Cells(searchRngQue.End(xlUp).Row, 8), .Cells(searchRngQue.End(xlDown).Row, 8)))
```

When working with `Range(Cells(1,1), Cells(100,1))` you use a `,` as separator, not `:`

Comment: Yeah, otherwise you would need to get the cell.address to do the string representation of the range

Comment: Yeah, but that would be a little... overkill? :D

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Now, as a last question: How to I determine to beginning and ending row of searchRngQue? .end(xlup/down) does not to the trick...

Comment: `searchRngQue.Cells(1,1).Row` would be the first and `searchRngQue.Rows.Count` the last.

Comment: @Damian it certainly would but I just wanted to give the context for the OP to hopefully grasp the difference